# I'm trying to turn this python script into a web app with flask

Tags: python, flask, openai-api

I am trying to turn my script into a web app, it uses wordpress and chatgpt to generate articles based on keywords and what you type in the input boxes and allows the user to instantly upload to drafts on their wordpress site..
I am running into an issue:

**updated**

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
import openai
import requests
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'

# Set your OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = ""


class InputForm(FlaskForm):
    api_key = StringField('OpenAI API Key', validators=[InputRequired()])
    input_text = TextAreaField('Input Text', validators=[InputRequired()])
    keywords = TextAreaField('Keywords (comma-separated)', validators=[InputRequired()])
    wp_base_url = StringField('WordPress Base URL', validators=[InputRequired()])
    wp_username = StringField('WordPress Username', validators=[InputRequired()])
    wp_password = StringField('WordPress Password', validators=[InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


# Array holding wordpress author IDs
authorList = ["1", "2"]

# You can call the "gpt-3.5-turbo" model
modelEngine = "gpt-3.5-turbo"

# WordPress information
wp_base_url = ""
wp_username = ""
wp_password = ""


# Post creator function
def create_post(inputTitleSent, outputText):
    randomAuthor = random.choice(authorList)

    post_status = "draft"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    post = {
        "title": inputTitleSent,
        "content": outputText,
        "status": post_status,
        "author": randomAuthor,
        "categories:": "6"
    }
    url = wp_base_url + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
    response = requests.post(url, data=post, headers=headers, auth=(wp_username, wp_password))
    return response


# Post title creator function
def create_title(outputText):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model=modelEngine,
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": f"Write a title for this article:\n\n {outputText}"}],
        n=1
    )
    create_title = response.choices[0].message.content
    create_title = create_title.replace('"', '')
    return create_title


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    global wp_base_url, wp_username, wp_password  # Move the global declaration here

    form = InputForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Get user input from the form
        data = request.get_json()
        api_key = data.get('api_key')
        input_text = data.get('input_text')
        keywords = data.get('keywords')
        wp_base_url = data.get('wp_base_url')
        wp_username = data.get('wp_username')
        wp_password = data.get('wp_password')

        try:
            response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
                model=modelEngine,
                messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Testing API Key"}],
                n=1
            )

            if 'choices' not in response or not response['choices']:
                flash("Invalid API Key. Please check and try again.", "error")
                return render_template('index.html', form=form, data=None)

            # ... (rest of the code remains the same)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            flash("Error occurred while connecting to the OpenAI API. Please check your internet connection and try again.", "error")
            return render_template('index.html', form=form, data=None)

        except Exception as e:
            flash("An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.", "error")
            return render_template('index.html', form=form, data=None)

    return render_template('index.html', form=form, data=None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the requests  are getting sent to the server on debug but it doesn't run the script when pressing submit and the inputs doesn't render, how can I fix this?

index.html **(updated)**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OpenAI WordPress Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Input your information:</h1>
    <form id="inputForm" method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.api_key.label }} {{ form.api_key(id='api_key', size=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.input_text.label }} {{ form.input_text(id='input_text', rows=10, cols=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.keywords.label }} {{ form.keywords(id='keywords', rows=3, cols=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.wp_base_url.label }} {{ form.wp_base_url(id='wp_base_url', size=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.wp_username.label }} {{ form.wp_username(id='wp_username', size=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.wp_password.label }} {{ form.wp_password(id='wp_password', size=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </form>

    {% if data %}
        <h1>Generated Posts:</h1>
        {% for post in data %}
            <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <script>
        document.getElementById('inputForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting normally
            var api_key = document.getElementById('api_key').value;
            var input_text = document.getElementById('input_text').value;
            var keywords = document.getElementById('keywords').value;
            var wp_base_url = document.getElementById('wp_base_url').value;
            var wp_username = document.getElementById('wp_username').value;
            var wp_password = document.getElementById('wp_password').value;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        // Request successful, update the page if necessary
                        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        if (response.error) {
                            alert('Error: ' + response.error);
                        } else {
                            alert('Data processed successfully!');
                            // Optionally, you can update the page with the generated posts here
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Handle error here
                        alert('Error occurred. Please try again later.');
                    }
                }
            };

            var data = JSON.stringify({
                api_key: api_key,
                input_text: input_text,
                keywords: keywords,
                wp_base_url: wp_base_url,
                wp_username: wp_username,
                wp_password: wp_password
            });

            xhr.send(data);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide the index.html please ?

Comment: Yes, index.html has been added to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edir your index.html :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>OpenAI WordPress Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Input your information:</h1>
    <form id="inputForm" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('index') }}">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.api_key.label }} {{ form.api_key(id='api_key', size=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.input_text.label }} {{ form.input_text(id='input_text', rows=10, cols=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.keywords.label }} {{ form.keywords(id='keywords', rows=3, cols=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.wp_base_url.label }} {{ form.wp_base_url(id='wp_base_url', size=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.wp_username.label }} {{ form.wp_username(id='wp_username', size=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.wp_password.label }} {{ form.wp_password(id='wp_password', size=60) }}<br>
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </form>

    {% if data %}
        <h1>Generated Posts:</h1>
        {% for post in data %}
            <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}


</body>
</html>
```

and it will be you flask wtf form :

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import  DataRequired

class InputForm(FlaskForm):
    api_key = StringField('OpenAI API Key', validators=[DataRequired()])
    input_text = TextAreaField('Input Text', validators=[DataRequired()])
    keywords = TextAreaField('Keywords (comma-separated)', validators=[DataRequired()])
    wp_base_url = StringField('WordPress Base URL', validators=[DataRequired()])
    wp_username = StringField('WordPress Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    wp_password = StringField('WordPress Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

and tour index route will be you can just add you rest of your code problem was getting information right ?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print(request.method) # testing request method coming from your index.html form
    form = InputForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
    # Get user input from the for
        api_key = form.api_key.data
        input_text = form.input_text.data
        keywords = form.keywords.data
        wp_base_url = form.wp_base_url.data
        wp_username = form.wp_username.data
        wp_password = form.wp_password.data
        for item in form: # for testing your results
            print(item.data)
        # rest of your code 

return render_template('index.html', form=form, data=None)
```

Comment: For this part "Remove the javaScript that send you from data to your flask app" Which javaScript am I removing and on which file? App.py or Index.html

I edited the form to your new code in index.html but I need know where I should remove the javaScript you mentioned.

Comment: in index.html and tell me its works or not i face same problem  afew months agop and this solution fix my broblem

Comment: This still doesn't work... I edited the index.html form to your code and added the rest of my tags. I also changed in the "if form.validate_on_submit():" statement in app.py to your second part of the code and now I get Bad Request error page..

Comment: di you not forget to put your from  id="inputForm" ? i just edir my answer with full html right now if its dosent wokr sorry for that i take you time and i will delete my answer

Comment: No need to delete your post. I made the edits, I used your index.html but unfortunately it still doesn't render the inputs. I made updates to the post with what I currently have. Maybe you can look over it and see if I did anything wrong?

Comment: i test a flask app by writing in my ide and find the problem i just delete everything for handeling open ai api and focous on getting information from your flask form to your flask app pblem was in your validators and i change it from inputrequierd to Datarequied and i get data in flask appi will update my answer an i hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks, the form works, now I have to figure how to make openai API work with the form.

Comment: good luck with your project :)